# When can I "do, do" something?

Tags: word-order

Is it grammatically correct to use the word "do" twice in a row?
Examples:
We do do what you are talking about.
instead of...
We do what you are talking about.

or

Our process does do what you are talking about.
instead of...
Our process does what you are talking about.

Is the meaning any different?

Answer (score 6):

The use of *do* with another verb is for emphasis. It doesn't matter what the other verb is.

> We do want to invite you. It's just we don't have the space...
>
> We do love you. But this is for your own good.
>
> We do clean our car. But we drive through mud every day too.

There's no reason that *do* can't be the verb which is emphasised.

> We do that → We do do that.

Comment: This sort of emphasis is often used to counter a claim of inability, e.g. "It's too bad your process doesn't handle frobulation." "Oh, our process does do that."

Comment: Yes: perhaps my examples don't show that clearly, although they do show a similar rebuttal.

Comment: This sounds better than it looks. Putting the supporting _do_ in italics both indicates the stress and improves the appearance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually the verb after *do* can be stressed too. "We do *clean* our car. We don't vacuum the inside." It depends what the contrast/counter is. In fact in my first example either *do* or *want* could be stressed.

Comment: It wouldn't be normal with do _do_.

Comment: It could be. "We do *do* that, but it doesn't always work."

Comment: I still do not see how the meaning in "We do that, but it doesn't always work."  is any different from "We do do that, but it doesn't always work."  It seems redundant.  Is there some sort of tense in the verb that I am not grasping?  I could say "I did do that!"  or "I did that!"  It still has the same tense.

Comment: @ininn Tense? There's no difference in tense. It's redundant only in as much as it provides emphasis (so it says the same thing, only stronger). Thus "I said that" and "I did say that" describe exactly the same action -- saying something -- but the latter does so more forcefully. Replace the verb *say* with *paint* and you get "I painted that"/"I did paint that"; replace *say* with *do* and it becomes "I did that"/"I did do that".

Comment: @AndrewLeachI have a manager who over uses "do do" with this awkward pause in between the do's.  Maybe that is my problem.  It sounds like this manager is using the phrase to separate themselves from the action and having a loss of words in the process.  It ends up with less emphasis, and more separation despite what the Internet says..