# "What is it exactly you do do?"

Tags: word-order, indirect-question, do

In a Twin Peaks [episode](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/29c340e4-2564-4659-9393-7ae48a2f7083) you can hear the following question: "So, Mr. Wheeler, **what is it exactly you do do**?". It seems to me quite weird. Is it correct?
I suppose that the purpose of the second *do* isn't to emphasize something.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The sentence is fine; you can use *do* before most verbs to [add emphasis](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/071112/), including *do* itself. See *[When can I "do, do" something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412056/when-can-i-do-do-something)*

Comment: I haven't seen the episode, but I suspect that you're not showing emphasis in the way the actor delivered the line. My guess is that "Mr Wheeler" had said something to the effect of "I don't do that", and the actor delivering this line said it as "So, Mr Wheeler, what is it exactly that you ***do*** do?", in an effort to find out what Mr Wheeler does.

Comment: @choster - not a duplicate IMO, but certainly relevant.

Comment: The speaker is being sarcastic, with a very heavy emphasis on the first *do*. The implication is that Mr. Wheeler doesn't do anything (e.g. work for a living).

Comment: You should bear in mind that “Twin Peaks” was quite weird, by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking 'what is it exactly you do do?

Is a way of differentiating from 'what you don't do'. (Or indeed, whether you do anything at all!)

Example:

'I am a plumber, but I don't fix pipes, water heaters or baths!'

Reply 'what is it exactly you do do?'

'Well I only do radiators actually. And only on Wednesdays. If I'm not busy!'

Answer (score 0):

"What do you do?" is an idiomatic way of asking "What is your occupation/job?"

And if a plumber is asked to paint a house he might reply "I don't do painting."

The other party might then reply "What *do* you do?" (Emphasis on the first "do".)

To which a reasonable reply might be "I'm a plumber."

"What is it exactly you *do* do?" might be the response if a person who had identified himself as a "painter" were asked to paint a house and replied "I don't paint houses."  The implication is that the painter is somehow not of the profession his interrogator had assumed, so the interrogator wants more detail as to what *exactly* the painter *does*.

In such a case the painter might explain, "I'm an artist, I paint portraits."